# Firebase - GDPR+Schrems requires end-to-end encryption, but how?

Tags: firebase, encryption, firebase-authentication, privacy, standards-compliance

I need to protect a group of user’s data, i.e. to facilitate multiple invited users to read and contribute protected data.
My understanding is that I need to implement the following design:

1 . Each user gets authenticated with Firebase Auth (OAuth2 or email/password).

2 . Each user creates a public/private key-pair **(How?)**. The public keys can be shared in Firebase. **How to store the private key? Seems natural to store it in Firebase in encrypted form (passcode protected), but how?...**

2a. Either the users must manually store the passcode in e.g. a “personal password manager”. [Password protect private key](https://youtu.be/KuKvwjs6ENE?t=1439)

2b. Or could the passcode come from e.g. the OAuth 3rd party?

3 . Encrypt/decrypt data (support user group). Multi-user-data requires an extra layer for having a common (symmetrical) key **(How?)**, so all invited users can encrypt and decrypt data. The group manager stores this common key in Firebase to all users, using their individual public keys. [Virgils story about the Creator](https://youtu.be/VmyqHou_fME?t=841).

So does the above requirement make sense(!), and how to get around compliance? **How to document such security measures?** Protecting your customer’s data might make you sleep at night, but you also need to convince the future customers that data will be safe.

I wonder why Firebase does not have a guide on all this, to safely facilitate GDPR. The topic seems such a show stopper nowadays.

All constructive input are highly appreciated!

Comment: GDPR has no such requirements. In makes no demands for specific implementations, only data protection outcomes. It does require you to keep your promises – so if you say you’re doing e2e, you must actually do it. The problem you describe is thus a technical one, and is indeed difficult. I’d recommend looking into how Signal’s protocols achieve it, and perhaps even use them.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#data_encryption.

Comment: @Synchro thanks. I have added 'Schrems' to the title to clarify the practical needs.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec thanks. To my understanding Firebase does not provide any e2ee to ensure data privacy.

Comment: Schrems doesn’t have any particular bearing on e2ee either!